# Python SQLAlchemy INSERT after DELETE violates constraint

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have this pattern for deletion of all rows in a Postgresql table and subsequent insertion with SQLAlchemy:

```
db = create_engine("postgresql://...", echo=False).connect()
metadata = MetaData(db)
my_table = Table('my_table', metadata, autoload_with=db)
...
db.execute(my_table.delete())
db.execute(my_table.insert(), values)
```

where `values` is a list.

I can't uderstand why I get a `psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation` when trying to insert.

The data which is inserted is not duplicated, so I guess the problem is that the delete is not committed?

I don't use a `Session`: what do I need to do to get this simple pattern working correctly?

Comment: How about using transaction?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQLAlchemy Delete And Insert in Same Transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34169599/sqlalchemy-delete-and-insert-in-same-transaction)

Comment: @noninertialframe I will try. But do I really need to use a session and a transaction for this simple pattern? I'm trying to understand what I'm missing from SqlAlchemy documentation. Clearly I'm missing something obvious...

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by completely disabling automatic SQLAlchemy transactions (which are not needed in my case of bulk deletions/insertions) with the supported DBAPI `isolation_level="AUTOCOMMIT"`:

```
db = create_engine("postgresql://...", echo=False).connect().execution_options(isolation_level="AUTOCOMMIT")
```

See https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#setting-transaction-isolation-levels-including-dbapi-autocommit